# Conditional Expectation of X over the sigma algebra generated by X

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

> For a probability space $(S,E,P)$ and integrable random variable $X$, if $G = \sigma(X)$ which is generated by a partition $C_1,C_2,\ldots$ with $P(C_i)>0 \ \forall\, i\in{1,2,\ldots}$, then what is $E[X\mid G]$?

Am I correct in that $E[X\mid G]=X$?

My thought was if we let $X(w)=x_i$ for $w \in C_i$. Then

$$E[X\mid C_i]=\frac{1}{P(C_i)}\int_{C_i}X\,dP=\frac{x_i}{P(C_i)}\int_{C_i}dP=x_i\frac{P(C_i)}{P(C_i)}=x_i$$

Comment: This can never be true since $\mathbb{E}[X|G]$ is per definition a random variable. This means that essentially anything in $G$ can have happened. This is not too bad, you just get something of the form $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 1_{C_i}(\omega)\cdot E_i$.

Comment: Moreover, $X(\omega)=x_i$ for $\omega\in C_i$ is not something that can be assumed.

Comment: I'm a little lost on what you're saying it would be; the sum of the probabilities of the partitions?  My thought was that E[X|G](w) = X(w), essentially.

Comment: The result is definitely true. I am sorry, I think I get the question now, you define your $C_i$ such that there is only one $\omega$ per $C_i$. Your proof is a bit sketchy though. I have the idea that you just have to stick to the definition of conditional expectation and pick a random set $B\in G$.